# Unable to call method in Python

Tags: python

Right now I have a method in my class that's really simple, but I'm have a hard time calling it.

```
def size(self):
  return self.size
```

The call I'm required to use is this:

```
print(str(ll.size()))
```

Which always leads to this output:

```
print(str(ll.size()))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I've been told several times it's the way I have the size() method set up, but I've never been able to understand it. Can someone show me the proper way to make a method that can be called like this and explain the difference for future reference? Thanks!

Comment: You can't have both a method `size` and an integer attribute named `size`.  They're the same name.  If you set `self.size = 1` you replace your method with the number.

Comment: You problem is quite simple. You have a instance field name `size` that presumably is an integer, and a method named `size` as well. When you attempt to access the size attribute, the instance attribute takes precedence of the method. The fix? Simply rename one of the attributes.

Comment: looks like you have an attribute size, and a method size - How about renaming the attribute to `_size` or something if you really need a method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your class has two attributes called `size`, one being the method you have defined and one being the property you're calling from inside your method.

From the error message you can tell that the second one is begin called. So, `ll.size` is an int and `ll.size()` is 'calling' that int.

Try to rename your method to something else than `size` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have both a instance variable name **size** and an instance method name **size**.

How would one distinguish them ?

Here the instance variable take  precedence because it was define first (you probably have a `self.size = x` in your `__init__` method and therefore appearing first in your object `__dict__`)  which is a `int` and therefore not callable.

If you have nothing special to do on the `size` value just use the attribute directly without defining a function:

```
class Foo:
        def __init__(self, somearg):
            # ...
            self.size = somearg * 3
>>> foo = Foo(3)
>>> foo.size
9
```

If you want to make something more complex *(contrary to my trivial example here)* use a [property](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, somearg):
        # ...
        self._size = None
        self._someattr = somearg
    # ...
    @property
    def size(self):
        if self._someattr > 2:
            return self._someattr * 3
        return 1
>>> foo = Foo(3)
>>> foo.size
9
>>> bar = Foo(2)
>>> bar.size
 1
```

To fully understand the advantage of the property decorator read [this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)